# Query based on sum of previous n rows with condition

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, window-functions

I have a table of football games with columns:

```
id,match_date,team1_id,team2_id,score_team1,score_team2
```

I need a result showing:

- id
- match_date
- team1_id
- team2_id
- points for team1 (3 - for the win, 1 - draw, 0 - loss) in previous 5 matches
- points for team2 in previous 5 matches
- points for team1 in previous 5 matches when it was team2(away game)
- points for team2 in previous 5 matches when it was team1(home game)

I tried to add columns with points for team1 and team2 but I can not figure out how to use window function to sum proper matches points.

Comment: It's typically easier for someone trying to help if you provide SQL scripts to setup a small table with test data and the expected output in a tabular format (the way your SQL client displays it). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables. You can use sites like https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12 to provide some sample scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous 5 matches can easily be calculated using a running total:

```
select id, team_1_id, team2_id, match_date,
       sum(case 
             when score_team1 = score_team2 then 1
             when score_team1 > score_team2 then 3
             else 0
           end) over (order by match_date rows between 4 preceding and current rows) as prev_score_team1,
       sum(case 
             when score_team2 = score_team1 then 1
             when score_team2 > score_team1 then 3
             else 0
           end) over (order by match_date rows between 4 preceding and current rows) as prev_score_team2
from game
order by match_date;
```

The definition of "5 previous games" is a bit unclear - does that include the "current match" (which is what the above query does) or does it *exclude* the row for which the sum is displayed? If it should exclude the current row you need `rows between 5 rows preceding and 1 preceding` instead.

It's also unclear to me, how the "away team" is identified, but if you have store the id of the away team in a column (or something similar), then you could use a `filter()` condition for the window function:

```
sum(case ... as above ... end) filter (where team_id = team1_id) over (... as above ..)
```

Comment: if team_id is in team1_id then it is 'home', in team2_id is 'away'. Like Real Madrid - Barcelona in real game. First position means home. Score here means number of goals of each team like 2:1,0:0. But I need points

Comment: @aplusk: you didn't mention a `team_id` column in your question, but you can use that for the `filter()` condition. You can calculate the points from the score, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

I made a rather complicate answer with cte, should work but quite long

Method: use row number for getting the team play order (overall, home/away) and sum up

See if anyone can have more simple answer for that

```
WITH cte (id, match_date, team1_id, team2_id, score1, score2, team1_order, team2_order, home_order, away_order) 
as
(
    select t.id, match_date, team1_id, team2_id,
    score1=case when score_team1 > score_team2 then 3 when score_team1 = score_team2 then 1 else 0 end,
    score2=case when score_team1 < score_team2 then 3 when score_team1 = score_team2 then 1 else 0 end,
    team1_order = p1.ord,
    team2_order = p2.ord,
    home_order, away_order
    from @t t
    join 
    (
        select id, team, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team order by match_date) ord
        from
        (select id, match_date, team1_id team from @t
         union all
         select id, match_date, team2_id team from @t) a
    ) p1 on p1.id=t.id and p1.team = team1_id
    join 
    (
        select id, team, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team order by match_date) ord
        from
        (select id, match_date, team1_id team from @t
         union all
         select id, match_date, team2_id team from @t) a
    ) p2 on p2.id=t.id and p2.team = team2_id
    join
    (
        select id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team1_id order by match_date) home_order,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team2_id order by match_date) away_order
        from @t
    ) p3 on p3.id=t.id
)

select c.id, c.match_date, c.team1_id, c.team2_id, score1, score2,
team1_prev=
(select isnull(sum(score1),0) from cte c11 where c11.team1_id = c.team1_id and c.team1_order - c11.team1_order between 1 and 5) +
(select isnull(sum(score2),0) from cte c12 where c12.team2_id = c.team1_id and c.team1_order - c12.team2_order between 1 and 5),
team2_prev=
(select isnull(sum(score1),0) from cte c21 where c21.team1_id = c.team2_id and c.team2_order - c21.team1_order between 1 and 5) +
(select isnull(sum(score2),0) from cte c22 where c22.team2_id = c.team2_id and c.team2_order - c22.team2_order between 1 and 5),
team1_prevhome=
(select isnull(sum(score1),0) from cte c3 where c3.team1_id = c.team1_id and c.home_order - c3.home_order between 1 and 5),
team2_prevaway=
(select isnull(sum(score2),0) from cte c4 where c4.team2_id = c.team2_id and c.away_order - c4.away_order between 1 and 5)
from cte c
order by id
```

BTW, @t is the original table since I use table variable for testing